# C++ unable to figure out crtp observer pattern design

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm trying to have a template design allowing automagic observer/observed capabilities. I got two suspects for this problem :

- the static inheritance that is not happening the way I'd expect on the `Observing::notify()`.
- the `TYPE::Status` templated parameter that I'm trying to bind to an `enum class` within the template `TYPE` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

// Observer base class
template <class TYPE>
struct Observing
{
    template <class STATUS = TYPE::Status>
    void notify(STATUS status);

protected:
    // Constructed only through inheritance
    Observing()  { TYPE::subscribe(this); }
    ~Observing() { TYPE::unsubscribe(this); }
};

// Class being observed
template <class TYPE>
struct Observable
{
    static void subscribe   (Observing<TYPE>* obs) { observers.insert(obs); }
    static void unsubscribe (Observing<TYPE>* obs) { observers.erase(obs); }
    static std::set<Observing<TYPE>*> observers;
};

// Static definition of observable object's observers container
template <class TYPE>
std::set<Observing<TYPE>*> Observable<TYPE>::observers;

// Implementation of an observable service
struct Service : Observable<Service>
{
    enum class Status { Up, Down };

    void broadcast(Status status)
    {
        for (Observing<Service>* obs : observers)
            obs->notify(status); // <--- unable to link `notify()`
    }
};

struct Process: Observing<Service>
{
    void notify(Service::Status status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
        case Service::Status::Up:   std::cout << "Service is UP\n"; break;
        case Service::Status::Down: std::cout << "Service is DOWN\n"; break;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Service service;
    Process worker;

    service.broadcast(Service::Status::Up);
}
```

I thought that maybe the definition of `Process::notify()` was too late, but I tried to put the declaration above `Service` and the definition below but then I have to forward-declare `Service` and can't find a way to declare `Service::Status`.

Maybe my approach is too convoluted though...

Comment: What do you mean by `unable to link `notify()``? Is the linker complaining?

Comment: you lost the type informations when storing it in the `std::set<Observing<Service>>`, so it will link to `Observing<Service>::notify` rather than `RealType::notify` because of lacking type information. use virtual function instead, CRTP is not for this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding what you want to implement won't work. In this code the compiler is able to find only one `notify` function in struct `Observing` which has no body. So the linker complains about it later.

```
 for (Observing<Service>* obs : observers)
     obs->notify(status); // <--- unable to link `notify()`
```

Lets try to help the compiler to pick the correct function. Since we are in compile-time we can use static_cast. Lets try:

```
static_cast<To what?>(obj)->notify(status);
```

The answer to this question (to what to static_cast) is obtainable at runtime only - which leads us to dynamic polymorphism.

So you'll have to try another solution: either use runtime polymorphism or to change the architecture of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the Observer pattern is that the subject doesn't know the static type of the observer. You are going to need `virtual`. That means that `notify` can't be a template, you will need to fix what member of `Observable` denotes the argument to `notify`.

```
template <class TYPE>
struct Observing
{
    using Status = typename TYPE::Status;

    virtual void notify(Status status);
    // ...
};
```

And for safety, add `override` where you override it

```
struct Process: Observing<Service>
{
    void notify(Status status) override;
};
```